# How to communicate return value and validation errors to the caller of a method?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am creating a class in the service layer of my Spring application.

One method is:

```
/**
* Creates a new user account.
* @return Returns true if the password reset went ok, otherwise false.
*/
boolean confirmPasswordReset(UserAccount account, String confirmationId, String newPassword);
```

However, this method signature is unable to give the caller any information about what could have made the confirmation to fail. I have validation rules; the password must not be the username, the password must have 8 characters and so on. If the user fails to provide a strong password I want to reject the confirmation and return false. However I also want to communicate the validation errors.

So I have the following solution, but I am unsure whether or not it is a good idea. This is my attempt:

(I use Java 8, hence the Optional class)

```
public class OperationResult<T> {

    private Optional<T> returnObject;
    private List<ConstraintViolation> violations;

    public OperationResult(Optional<T> returnObject, List<ConstraintViolation> violations) {
        this.returnObject = returnObject;
        this.violations = violations;
    }

    public Optional<T> getReturnObject() {
        return returnObject;
    }

    public List<ConstraintViolation> getViolations() {
        return violations;
    }
}
```

Then I change the return value of the service layer method to:

```
OperationResult<Boolean> confirmPasswordReset(UserAccount account, String confirmationId, String newPassword);
```

This is just one example, but I have several methods where this would be useful.

Does this look bad from a design point of view? Throwing an exception because the password is to weak, or the password is the same as the username does not look like a good solution.

Comment: If the password is too short and the same as the username would you then want to show both validation errors to the user or just one of them?

Comment: Both errors, I want to provide the caller with information on what is wrong.

Comment: Also note that Optional is not Serializable...

Comment: Is this in a JSF webapp? Ideally, the operation should not make it as far as calling `confirmPasswordReset` before alerting the user; web tier components (validators etc) should prevent that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw a custom Exception with the List violations in it:

```
void confirmPasswordReset(UserAccount account, String confirmationId, String newPassword) throws ValidationException
```

The ValidationException might be checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways I can see:

1. Return an Array or List with the validation errors:

   ```
   String[] confirmPasswordReset(UserAccount account, String confirmationId, String newPassword);
   ```

   In this case you would have to check length of the array returned. If the length is 0 then the password is valid.
2. You can keep the boolean value and pass an additional `List<String>` parameter, which then gets filled up with the validation errors from within the menthod.

   ```
    boolean confirmPasswordReset(UserAccount account, String confirmationId, String newPassword, List<String> aValidationErrors);
   ```

Additionally, instead of returning your validation as a String you could also define an `Enum` with the appropriate error messages.

Comment: Yeah, so basically what I have done here except that I have better encapsulation.